# How to properly override reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I would like to create a special animation for when I'm reloading the rows of a `UITableView`. The thing is I don't want to use this animation all the time, as I am sometimes using built-in animation for reloading the rows.

So how can I do this? By overriding `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` in my own UITableView implementation? How?

Or maybe there is a better way to get my own animation while reloading a row?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should not override `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`. Just implement a custom method `reloadRowsWithMyAnimationAtIndexPaths:`in UITableView's category and use it when it is needed.

But if you want to override this method in UITableView's subclass, you could do this:

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths 
              withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation {
    if (self.useMyAnimation) 
        [self reloadRowsWithMyAnimationAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    else
        [super reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:animation];
}
```

self.useMyAnimation is just a flag (BOOL property) that indicates what animation to use. Set this flag before reload operation.

For 2 or more customAnimations you could implement enum:

```
enum MyTableViewReloadAnimationType {
    case None
    case First
    case Second
    case Third
}
```

Then make a MyTableViewReloadAnimationType property (for example, reloadAnimationType) and select an appropriate animation method with switch:

```
    var reloadAnimationType = MyTableViewReloadAnimationType.None

    override func reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [AnyObject], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation) {
        switch self.reloadAnimationType {
        case .None:
            super .reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation:animation)
        default:
            self .reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withCustomAnimationType:self.reloadAnimationType)
        }
    }

    func reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [AnyObject], withCustomAnimationType animationType: MyTableViewReloadAnimationType) {
        switch animationType {
        case .First:
            self .reloadRowsWithFirstAnimationAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
        case .Second:
            self .reloadRowsWithSecondAnimationAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
        case .Third:
            self .reloadRowsWithThirdAnimationAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
        }
    }
```

You could call the custom method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withCustomAnimationType:` directly:

```
self.tableView .reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withCustomAnimationType: MyTableViewReloadAnimationType.First)
```

Inside the custom method you need to get a current cell and a new cell with method of dataSource:

```
func reloadRowsWithFirstAnimationAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [AnyObject]) {
    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        var currentCell = self .cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath as! NSIndexPath)
        var newCell = self.dataSource .tableView(self, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath as! NSIndexPath)
        var newCellHeight = self.delegate .tableView(self, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        var frame: CGRect = currentCell.frame
        frame.size.height = newCellHeight
        newCell.frame = frame
        self .replaceCellWithFirstAnimation(currentCell!, withAnotherCell: newCell);
    }
}

func replaceCellWithFirstAnimation(firstCell : UITableViewCell, withAnotherCell secondCell: UITableViewCell) {
    var cellsSuperview = firstCell.superview!
    //make this with animation
    firstCell .removeFromSuperview()
    cellsSuperview .addSubview(secondCell)
}
```

You need to handle a situation when newCell's height > or < then currentCell's height. All other cells frames must be recalculated. I think it could be done with beginUpdates and endUpdates methods. Call them before the manipulation with cells.

Comment: No worries for Objective C. I can read it, as long as I don't have to write it... Regarding `self.useMyAnimation` how do you use it? I did the same except that the `if` was about the `animation` being nil or not as I didn't find another way. But it's more a hack than a proper solution, if I have two custom animation, it doesn't work. And how do you reload the cell?

Comment: The problem is when you call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`, you can only specify (correct me if I'm wrong) the type of animation with a `UITableViewRowAnimation`. And there is only one declaration of `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`. I don't mind not overriding this method and stay make a custom reload method but how do you then reload the cell?

Comment: Lets look at last code sample in my answer. Before reload operation you need to set reloadAnimationType of your table view, then call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation. If reloadAnimationType == .None, this method will call implementation of super (UITableView). If reloadAnimationType has another value, this method will call your custom implementation. The type of animation (UITableViewRowAnimation) is needed only for built-in implementation of super class. The custom type of animation (MyTableViewReloadAnimationType) is needed only for you custom implementations.

Comment: Ok but how do you reload (refresh if you prefer) the cell? The method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withCustomAnimationType`, except the animation part, what is inside?

Comment: that's actually what is in `replaceCellWithFirstAnimation` that I'm looking for. I don't know how to reload a cell. Let's put aside the animation and pretend I just made a change to my cell. If I want to see the change in my cell, how do I refresh the cell's display?

Comment: I changed code in last sample. It might help you. But you need to handle a situation when newCell height > or < then currentCell height. All other cells frames must be recalculated.

Comment: The problem with removing the cell view from its superView is that it requires some of extra work (as the views inside the cell come from Interface Builder) and might be a bit too heavy. I found another solution which is to just re set the cell as I did it in `tableView(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: You can't just re-set cell's properties because in some situations your new cell can be completely different (another class and xib). You can do this only if your table view has one cell prototype.

Comment: In my case, cells won't change size, the updates are just about some labels inside. Yes there is only one cell prototype